# maximum likelihood method

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Let's say that we had an information for men and women heights.

r code:

```
set.seed(1) 
Women=rnorm(80, mean=168, sd=6) 
Men=rnorm(120, mean=182, sd=7) 
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
hist(Men, xlim=c(150, 210), col="skyblue") 
hist(Women, xlim=c(150, 210), col="pink")
```

Unfortunately something happened and we lost the information who is women and who is men.

r code:

```
heights=c(Men, Women) 
par(mfrow=c(1,1)) 
hist(heights, col="gray70") 
rm(women, men)
```

Could we somehow estimate women and men mean heights and standard deviation using maximum likelihood method?
We know that men and women heights are normally distributed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Now answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/555033/119261.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical clustering or unsupervised classification problem.
The usual solution uses the well known EM algorithm (look for it on internet).